# How can a .NET 4.5.2 app still compile on a build server with only 4.5.1 installed?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, tfsbuild, .net-4.5.2

This has me completely baffled. I am testing upgrading our build infrastructure to .NET 4.5.2, which is currently on .NET 4.5.1.

My first step was to create an ASP.NET MVC project on my developer machine targeting .NET 4.5.2. I am using VS 2013 and have the 4.5.2 Developer Pack installed. I have written some superfluous code utilizing methods that are only supported in .NET 4.5.2:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (!Response.HeadersWritten)
        Response.AddOnSendingHeaders((c) => { c.Response.AddHeader("Foo", "Bar"); });

    return View();
}
```

[`Response.HeadersWritten`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.httpresponse.headerswritten.aspx) and [`Response.AddOnSendingHeaders`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.httpresponse.addonsendingheaders.aspx) are only introduced in the .NET 4.5.2 version of `System.Web.dll`. As expected, this compiles fine locally.

Prior to upgrading the build server to 4.5.2 I thought I'd just run a build of the above project on the build server from source control to see it fail. However the build completes successfully, only reporting the following warning:

> **The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"
>   were not found.** To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for
>   this framework version or retarget your application to a version of
>   the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed.
>   Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache
>   (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore
>   your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you
>   intend.

I pull down the compiled binaries from the drop to my local machine and the app runs fine and adds the `foo` header.

How does this 4.5.2 code compile! There are no local references to System.Web checked into the source being built and there is nothing being pulled in through a nuget package or such.

Comment: Do you specify in your configuration that 4.5.2 must be the framework target?  If so, relax that restriction.  If not, I don't see why you would get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tracked this down to the version of `System.Web.dll` in the GAC that is being referenced during the build. Despite all the documentation stating that `Response.HeadersWritten` and `Response.AddOnSendingHeaders` are only introduced in .NET 4.5.2, the following security update for .NET 4.5/4.5.1 installed a version of System.Web.dll into the GAC that does include those methods:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2894854

This explains why the compilation still succeeds. When forcing the build to compile targeting 4.5.1, using the `/p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.5.1` msbuild switch, the `System.Web.dll` reference is an older version pulled from the following location, which does not include those methods and therefore fails to compile as expected:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Web.dll`

Comment: That's because 4.5.2 was an *in-place* update, so 4.5.2 replaced any 4.5.1 dlls that changed (such as System.Web.dll). See http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx and https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Mar/13/NET-45-is-an-inplace-replacement-for-NET-40 for details.

Answer (score 0):

If your app doesn't use anything that's particular to v4.5.2 (or got obsoleted or changed in a breaking way), you should be good.

- [Application Compatibility in the .NET Framework 4.5.2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn720543(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [What's new in the .NET Framework 4.5.2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868(v=vs.110).aspx#v452)

Or course, it could be B^) that you just haven't encountered the particular execution path(s) where things go south.

Further, one might note that [4.5.2 was an *in-place* update to 4.x family](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/08/07/moving-to-the-net-framework-4-5-2.aspx), so you get the same DLLs regardless of what 4.x version you're running.

Comment: I am using the two methods mentioned that only exist in 4.5.2. If I force the build to compile targeting 4.5.1, using the `/p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.5.1` msbuild switch, then the build fails to compile as I'd expect. I just don't understand why the build succeeds without that switch given 4.5.2 is not installed on the build server and the warning about the 4.5.2 reference assemblies being not being found occurs.